# "Literary inquisition" or "speech crime" Or is there a better term?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

The wiki said it is [Literary Inquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_inquisition)

> It refers to official persecution of intellectuals for their writings in China ...
> the rulers deliberately extracted words or phrases from intellectual's writings and arbitrarily accused him in order to persecute him.

It happened throughout China's long history in every dynasty. "Literary inquisition" or "speech crime" does not feel right.

For someone who knows little about this part of history, I will explain to them that it is like the Thoughtcrime in 1984 and it is not anti-intellectual per ser but to intimidate any free-thinking.  But censorship doesn't convey the meaning of Literary Inquisition because its purpose is to put the author of that written work in jail to frighten him and any newcomers.

I also asked ChatGPT and it said you may try "witch hunt against written works" or just "witch hunt of words".

But I was hoping to see a better term.

Comment: Are you asking for a better term than literary inquisition when politics is anti-intellectual and uses distortion to terrorize its own population?

Comment: 'Literary inquisition' seems to be fairly widely used, and the examples I've seen on the internet restricted to the example in China. But there have been suppressions/persecutions of people whose writings were considered seditious in many nations over the centuries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth asked a related question https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71590/did-literary-inquisitionhappen-in-other-country in history SE

Comment: I asked ChatGPT and it said you may try  witch-hunt of words. lol

Comment: "Persecution of the intelligentsia" perhaps?

Comment: Preventing people from writing freely is commonly called "censorship". Is that what you mean, or do you need something more specific?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan The action for which the word is required is exemplified in *“If you give me six lines written by the hand of the most honest of men, I will find something in them which will hang him.” ― Cardinal Richelieu (1585–1642) - to which the challenge was "God save the King!" Richelieu replied: "How do you know the king need saving? What part do you play in the plot against his life?"* The word will express that action.

Comment: Opinion-related offenses are "crimes of opinion". *The universal declaration of human rights  protects your right to hold your own opinions and to express them freely without government interference*.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan censorship doesn't convey the meaning of Literary Inquisition because its purpose is to put the author of that written work in jail to frighten him and any newcomers.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 Got it, and I see that you've specified that in the question now. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I run across this NYTimes article https://cn.nytimes.com/business/20210301/china-online-censorship/dual/ so it used **Speech Crimes** (but the url used "censorship" lol). BTW, I pasted the dual-language version link because it was a paid article for the English-only version.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 Yes, "speech crime" refers to the offense itself, not the government's actions. [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_crimes) doesn't discuss that phrase's origin, but I suspect that it is at least partly influenced by Orwell's "[thoughtcrime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoughtcrime)".

Comment: Sadly this had( or has) been practiced in China for 2000 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, there appears to be no single noun for this, yet it has been recognised for centuries, if not longer. In English, it is summed up by the well-known

> “If you give me six lines written by the hand of the most honest of men, I will find something in them which will hang him.” ― Cardinal Richelieu (1585–1642) - to which the challenge was "God save the King!" Richelieu replied: "How do you know the king needs saving? What part do you play in the plot against his life?"

The overall action may be a show-trial as a result of a witch-hunt; the evidence may be fabricated or manipulated; the accused may be vilified before and during the trial, and selective quotes may taken out of context and deliberately misinterpreted.

But there is no word for the latter.

Comment: I think it is probably the best answer I can get. BTW in a similar question I asked in history SE https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71590/did-literary-inquisition-happen-in-other-country I listed 5 examples, I think the western version of  "Literary inquisition"

Comment: It is a pity that the History SE question was closed. The Chinese "Literary inquisition" seems to be very specific and to have targeted authors as a group. The other "inquisitions" that you mention seem to have targeted individuals who had views contrary to the regime and often included "evidence" from writings (including personal letters), but never relied entirely on this.

Comment: I run across this NYTimes article https://cn.nytimes.com/business/20210301/china-online-censorship/dual/ so it used **Speech Crimes**. BTW, I pasted the dual-language version link because it was a paid article for the English-only version.

Comment: The article and the phrase "Speech Crimes" is unhelpful. Your question was clearly one of extracting sentences from context and using these as a basis for persecution. The article, in contrast, speaks of over-sensitivity to legitimate criticism. You should make the distinction.

Comment: Yes I know the article was talking about. I just let you know that even they used **speech crimes** and like you said "Strangely, there appears to be no single noun for this".

Comment: "It is a pity that the History SE question was closed." I tried to edit my question twice, hoping it would be reopened. But only it didn't (twice), I also got 3 downvotes so far. I have to say in a way I experience **censorship** in that particular question. :(